# How to attach and mount an EBS volume (NVM) in Ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an `aws` ebs volume. And it has some data, so I need to attach it to an ec2 instance and mount it so I can access those data:

1. Attached the ebs to ec2 instance

```
[root@jananathbanuka~]# sudo lsblk -f

NAME          FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
nvme1n1       xfs          ajha8a65-hja6-4cef-96c8-278562ch7726 /mnt
nvme0n1
├─nvme0n1p1   xfs    /     8ayha9wj-d5ff-494b-adf1-ajha6a4ahabj /
└─nvme0n1p128
nvme2n1
├─nvme2n1p1   xfs    /     97agajj1-d155-47e0-9121-anha5a543ahj
└─nvme2n1p128
[root@jananathbanuka ~]#
```

The newly atached ebs voilume is shown as `nvme2n1`

2. So I tried to mount it:

```
mkdir -p /test_mount
mount /dev/nvme2n1 /test_mount
```

But when I do that I get the following error:

> mount: /test_mount: unknown filesystem type.

So I tried `mount /dev/nvme2n1 /test_mount -t xfs`

And I get the following error:

> mount: /test_mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme2n1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

How can I mount this EBS volume successfully and read the data?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use below steps and it will work. i just did it and worked like charm

```
sudo mkfs -t xfs -f /dev/nvme2n1 
sudo file -s /dev/nvme2n1 
mkdir -p /test_mount
sudo mount -t xfs /dev/nvme2n1  /test_mount
```